# How to organize the definitions of signals when writing code with multiple classes that use pydispatcher for message dispatch

Tags: python, events, signals

I have been thinking of creating a signals module and declaring all the signal definitions there, but not sure if that is a smart approach. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I have used the same approach as yours, having a Java background, I wanted to have a class with static fields containing the signals. So say you have a `helper` folder in your project, you want to put there a `signals.py`and import it.